# Error "ImproperlyConfigured at /dj-rest-auth/login/" in use "dj_rest_auth"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dj-rest-auth

I Want Use packeage 'dj_rest_auth' in django-rest-framework for login but get error:

*ImproperlyConfigured at /dj-rest-auth/login/
No default throttle rate set for 'dj_rest_auth' scope*

In setting.py File:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    # 3rd Party
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'dj_rest_auth',

    # local
    ...
]


REST_USE_JWT = True

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'dj_rest_auth.jwt_auth.JWTCookieAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES':[
        'rest_framework.throttling.AnonRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.UserRateThrottle',
        'rest_framework.throttling.ScopedRateThrottle',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES':{
        'anon':'50/hour',
        'user':'200/hour',
        'register':'5/hour',
        'ref_token':'5/minute',
        'create_article':'5/minute',
    }
}
```

And url.py:
`urlpatterns = [ ... path('dj-rest-auth/',include('dj_rest_auth.urls')), ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR**
Add this into your settings.py file

```
'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': { 
    'dj_rest_auth': '10000/day',
    ...
},
```

or set the `throttle_scope` within the view to something else like `anon`.

Experienced the same issue and found this line within the project code

https://github.com/iMerica/dj-rest-auth/blob/4b3a4ce846c1fd358dfb1ff9fa3fdc8120d884f9/dj_rest_auth/views.py#L274

The view sets a custom throttle scope which you would not have configured within the `REST_FRAMEWORK` section of the `settings.py` file hence the error. No idea why they would make this change and not document it correctly.